# Using MVC asp-controller helper in Razor pages - what is best practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I am converting some MVC example code to use in a Razor pages application I am building. In the original MVC code, some of the links use the following asp helpers (for instance):

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Preview" asp-route-id="option">A link</a>
```

In the original MVC code there is a `HomeController` controller class defined.

I can get this to work in my Razor pages app if I have a page called 'Preview' in a directory called 'Home' under the 'Pages' folder. I then map the route using the @pages directive putting

```
@page "{option}"
```

at the top of the 'Preview.cshtml' page and passing a string to the `OnGet` method in the class definition of `PreviewModel` in the Preview.cshtml.cs file.

This works OK but is it what I should be doing? There is no `HomeController` in the Razor pages application, so is there a best practice Razor pages way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rely on the combination of the controller and action to always generate the correct route. You should change the tag helper to use the asp-page attribute instead.

```
<a asp-page="/Home/Preview" asp-route-id="option">A link</a>
```

See more about routing in Razor Pages here (my site): https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.